# Generalization of argument's types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

```
divide_list :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])

divide_list n [] l r = (l,r)
divide_list n (h:t) l r =
    if h <= n
      then divide_list n t (h:l) r
      else divide_list n t l (h:r)
```

As you can see my function takes list of `Int`. How to modify this code to get more general type? I mean for example list of String etc.

Comment: One simple solution is to evaluate the function without type signature and let ghci infer the type for you. It should generalize `Int` to `Ord a => a`.

Comment: What does it mean: "Ord a => a"?

Comment: It's any type `a` with an instance of `Ord`. It's needed for the use of `<=` in your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make a function polymorphic, you need to specify a *type variable* in the function's signature. Type variables must be specified in lower-case to distinguish them from specific types, which are specified in upper-case.

```
 divide_list :: a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Quote from *A Gentle Introduction to Haskell* tutorial:

> Haskell also incorporates polymorphic types---types that are
>   universally quantified in some way over all types. Polymorphic type
>   expressions essentially describe families of types. For example,
>   (forall a)[a] is the family of types consisting of, for every type a,
>   the type of lists of a. Lists of integers (e.g. [1,2,3]), lists of
>   characters (['a','b','c']), even lists of lists of integers, etc., are
>   all members of this family.

**EDIT after question in comment:**

Note that in your function definition you use `<=`. This is a function defined in the `Ord` typeclass, so you have to constraint the polymorphic type to be an instance of this typeclass.

```
divide_list :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Comment: OK, after it I got a compilation error ( It is obvious becasue Haskell doesn't know what does it mean: ((<=) e n). But how to repair it?

Comment: This type signature is too polymorphic -- you need an `Ord a` instance for the `e <= n` bit.

Comment: Ok. How to define my own type and amke him Ord?

Comment: @Gilgamesz Well, that's a completely different question then the original one. I advise you to search for the answer online. I'm sure you'll find plenty of useful information to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only aspect of `Int`s you use is that given `h` and `n`, you can compute `h <= n`. This is generalized in the `Ord` typeclass, so your function can be polymorphic over any choice of type variable `a`, as long as there is an `Ord a` instance:

```
divide_list :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Comment: What does it mean '=>'?